# Basic с чего начать?

Tags: visual-basic

С чего начать изучение этого языка программирования?

Comment: Имеется ввиду VB или QB? какой именно вас интересует? их там много

Comment: Visual Basic

Answer (score 1):

- [Знакомство с Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vbasic/ms789056)
- [Загрузка Visual Basic Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/)
- [Начинающим разработчикам](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vbasic/ms789097)